# Aggregate sum of certain rows with partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that has player stakes and wins on slot games. The data we receive has stake and win transactions on separate rows and we want to be able to put them on the same row, so we can attribute each win to the stake it came from.

The following gives an example of the data

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (PlayerID smallint,GameID smallint,GamePlayDateTime varchar(20),StakeGBP money,WinGBP money);
INSERT INTO #temp1 (PlayerID,GameID,GamePlayDateTime,StakeGBP,WinGBP)
VALUES 
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:38',  '0.4',  '0.0'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:41',  '0.0',  '0.6'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:44',  '0.4',  '0.0'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:46',  '0.4',  '0.0'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:49',  '0.0',  '1.2'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:51',  '0.0',  '0.2'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:54',  '0.0',  '1.0'),
('123', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:56',  '0.4',  '0.0'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:39',  '0.2',  '0.0'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:42',  '0.0',  '0.8'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:45',  '0.0',  '0.4'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:47',  '0.2',  '0.0'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:50',  '0.0',  '1.2'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:53',  '0.2',  '0.0'),
('824', '321',  '2019-08-20 10:21:55',  '0.2',  '0.0');
```

With the following output

```
PlayerID GameID GamePlayDateTime     StakeGBP              WinGBP
-------- ------ -------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:38  0.40                  0.00
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:41  0.00                  0.60
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:44  0.40                  0.00
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:46  0.40                  0.00
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:49  0.00                  1.20
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:51  0.00                  0.20
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:54  0.00                  1.00
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:56  0.40                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:39  0.20                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:42  0.00                  0.80
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:45  0.00                  0.40
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:47  0.20                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:50  0.00                  1.20
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:53  0.20                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:55  0.20                  0.00
```

Where a stake does not lead to a win, the next row is the subsequent stake. Any win transaction comes through in the row after the stake it belongs to, with StakeGBP = 0.

In the above example we want the 0.6 win at 10:21:41 to be on the same line as the 0.4 stake at 10:21:38 (the previous row). The GamePlayDateTime that is returned is not important (can either be the time of the stake or the time of the win), we just want to know that the 0.40 stake returned a 0.60 win.

I've previously been able to use a LAG function to take the stake from the previous row where the win is > 0.

The issue I have is that there are cases where one stake can lead to multiple wins. We want to be able to aggregate those wins and have them on the same line as the stake.

In the above example, a 0.40 stake at 10:21:46 leads to wins of 1.2, 0.2 and 1.0 before the next stake of 0.4 at 10:21:56.

What we want to do is sum those stakes, to give a win of 2.4, and have that win on the same row at the 0.4 stake it originated from.

The desired results from the above example would be

```
PlayerID GameID GamePlayDateTime     StakeGBP              WinGBP
-------- ------ -------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:38  0.40                  0.60
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:44  0.40                  0.00
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:46  0.40                  2.40
123      321    2019-08-20 10:21:56  0.40                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:39  0.20                  1.20
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:47  0.20                  1.20
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:53  0.20                  0.00
824      321    2019-08-20 10:21:55  0.20                  0.00
```

Where a stake does not lead to a win, the WinGBP column on the stake row is 0.
Where a stake leads to a single win, the WinGBP column shows the win on the same row as the stake (e.g. the first 0.6 win)
Where a stake leads to multiple wins, these wins are aggregated and appear on the same row as the stake (e.g. the 2.40 win, which comes from individual wins of 1.2, 0.2 and 1.0)

I haven't worked out how to use LAG when trying to return values from more than one row.

I've also tried to use SUM OVER to get a running total for the multiple wins, but haven't been able to work out how to partition it. The running total would need to stop when the WinGBP = 0, as that signals that a new stake has been placed.

If there is no win then we just want to return the stake. If there is one win then we want to return the stake (from the previous row) and the win. If there are multiple wins then we want to return the stake (from the row before the first win) and then aggregate the wins into one. The aggregation would then need to stop at the last win.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I realize that I follow the logic when someone which money.  I don't follow the logic for the rows where there is no win.

Comment: Aside: Why are all of the `smallint` and `money` values in your sample data quoted strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        sum(case when StakeGBP > 0 then 1 end)
            over (partition by PlayerID, GameID order by GamePlayDateTime) as StakeNum
    from temp1
)
select
    PlayerID,
    GameID,
    min(GamePlayDateTime) as GamePlayDateTime,
    max(StakeGBP) as StakeGBP,
    sum(WinGBP) as WinGBP
from data
group by PlayerID, GameID, StakeNum
order by PlayerID, GameID, GamePlayDateTime;
```

EDIT: Adjusted to handle players and games separately.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6b22/20

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting variant on a gaps-and-islands problem, where you only want to group the winning rows together.

You can identify the islands as the sum of the stakes up to each row.  Then the rest is basically aggregation and filtering:

```
select playerid, gameid, min(GamePlayDateTime) as GamePlayDateTime,
       sum(WinGBP) as WinGBP,
       sum(StakeGBP)) over (partition by playerid, gameid order by min(GamePlayDateTime) as prev_StakeGBP
 from (select t.*,
               sum(StakeGBP) over (partition by playerid, gameid order by GamePlayDateTime) as grp 
       from temp1 t
      ) t
group by playerid, gameid, grp, StakeGBP
order by playerid, gameid, GamePlayDateTime;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6b22/21) is a SQL Fiddle.